# For Loop by Button onClick in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How can we write a code that for example if user click a button, then 20 text or 20 of our function be created inside our Column below the Button?

Because we can't write the for loop inside the button click, because we get the: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function` Error

Comment: Do you wish to create 20 Composables below `Button` when you click it once?

Comment: yeah. a Text for example. in fact, I want to make a Text for each record that I have in my SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add to `mutableStateListOf`, delete from it or update an item with new instance recomposition will be triggered and inside a for loop you can create `Text` for each data contained in `SnapshotStateList`.

```
@Composable
private fun AddComposablesInLoopSample() {
    val myList: SnapshotStateList<String> = remember {
        mutableStateListOf()
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            myList.addAll(getData())
        }) {
            Text("Get Data")
        }

        myList.forEach {
            Text(it)
        }
    }
}

private fun getData(): List<String> {
    val myList = mutableListOf<String>()
    repeat(20) {
        myList.add("Row $it")
    }

    return myList.toList()
}
```

`getData` function is for demonstration to fill list.

Result

[image]